# simultaneously read and ioctl to USB hiddev files

Tags: usb, ioctl, hid-device

I am trying to access /dev/usb/hiddevX files via ioctl and read functions.
First of all I start a blocking read (new thread) to receive hid-events.
This works fine as long as I do not access the device via ioctl. After this I do not get any hid events anymore (the blocking read does not return).

For all operations the same file-handler is used (read/ioctl).
Is this normal beheavior? Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much,
Tom